Case insensitivity in vb.net Dictionaries keys
I only recently came across Option Compare Text in a roundabout fashion. We have all sorts of:
soAndSo.Equals("one", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)

and it seemed the option would be useful. However, many of those comparisons are in the keys of dictionaries, so I did this...
Option Compare Text
'Option Compare Binary
Dim testdict As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
testdict.Add("OneTwo", "onetwo")
testdict.Add("TwoThree", "twothree")
testdict.Add("ThreeFour", "threefour")
If "one" = "One" Then
    Dim y As Integer = 5
End If
If testdict.ContainsKey("onetwo") Then
    Dim y As Integer = 5
End If
If testdict.ContainsValue("OneTwo") Then
    Dim y As Integer = 5
End If
If testdict.ContainsValue("onetwo") Then
    Dim y As Integer = 5
End If

And that does not work, changing the Option has no effect, neither the dictionary keys or values match. I was surprised by this, as it seems MS is not using their own blessed equality tests.
I know I can make a dictionary with a different comparison operation, but I'm wondering if I've simply missed some equally simple switch? Google says no, but I don't trust google any more.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.-ctor?view=net-8.0#system-collections-generic-dictionary-2-ctor(system-collections-generic-iequalitycomparer((-0)))

I doubt the option works inside of a class

Dictionary is hash-based, so simply updating the comparisons isn't enough, you also need to update the hashing function.  You might have more success with SortedDictionary, though it may still require providing a custom comparison class as the default may run through the Framework without hitting anything controlled by the VB option.

As for why Microsoft never did anything automatically for Option Compare Text, it might be that nobody ever thought to do it, or it might be that they mainly intend for Option Compare Text to support backward compatibility for VBA-based VB code and want to push toward using things like StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase and custom IEqualityComparer(Of T) interfaces instead of changing behavior based on option settings.

As noted by @DanielA.White you can pass StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase into the dictionary constructor: Dim testdict As New Dictionary(Of String, String)(StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase).  This comparer implements a hash code method as well as an equality method so does what you need.  See Dictionary - StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase.  Does that C# question answer yours also?

A short example that causes the dictionary to ignore case,
    Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of String, String)(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)

    Dim ent As String = "TEST"

    dict.Add(ent, ent)
    If dict.ContainsKey(ent.ToLower) Then
        Debug.WriteLine("duplicate") 'here in debugger
    Else
        dict.Add(ent.ToLower, ent)
    End If


This does indeed solve the problem, at the cost of a LOT of editing. Have to see if it's worthwhile, code review follows in 3...2...1
